# def loadfile(self, filename): with open('ymtkyo.wav', 'rb') as stf_file: self.load(stf_file)に何が入っているかをpycharmとjupyter notebook確認したい

Tags: python

全くのプログラム初心者な質問ですがどうかご教授願います。

元にしているプログラムはこちらのものです。
https://sunpro.io/c89/pub/hiromu/ch03

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
import os
import struct
import sys

class STF:
    def __init__(self, filename = None):
        self.endian = '>'
        self.chunks = ['APSG', 'F0', 'SPEC']

    def loadfile(self, filename):
        with open('ymtkyo.wav', 'rb') as stf_file:
            self.load(stf_file)

    def load(self, stf_file):
        filesize = os.fstat(stf_file.fileno()).st_size

        while stf_file.tell() < filesize:
            chunk = stf_file.read(4)

            if chunk == 'STRT':
                if stf_file.read(2) == '\xff\xfe':
                    self.endian = '<'
                chunk_size, self.version, self.channel, self.frequency = struct.unpack(self.endian + 'IHHI', stf_file.read(12))
            else:
                chunk_size, = struct.unpack(self.endian + 'I', stf_file.read(4))

                if chunk == 'CHKL' or chunk == 'NXFL':
                    data = stf_file.read(chunk_size)
                    if chunk == 'CHKL':
                        self.chunks += [data[i: i + 4] for i in range(0, chunk_size, 4) if data[i: i + 4] not in self.chunks]
                else:
                    self.shift_length, frame_count, argument, self.bit_size, self.weight, data_size = struct.unpack(self.endian + 'dIIHdI', stf_file.read(30))
                    data = stf_file.read(data_size)

                    element = data_size / (self.bit_size / 8)
                    matrix = numpy.fromstring(data, count = element)

                    for c in self.chunks:
                        if chunk == c:
                            if element / frame_count == 1:
                                self.__dict__[c.strip()] = matrix
                            else:
                                self.__dict__[c.strip()] = matrix.reshape((frame_count, element / frame_count))
                            break

        for c in self.chunks:
            if c.strip() not in self.__dict__:
                self.__dict__[c.strip()] = None

    def savefile(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'wb') as stf_file:
            self.save(stf_file)

    def save(self, stf_file):
        stf_file.write('STRT')
        if self.endian == '>':
            stf_file.write('\xfe\xff')
        elif self.endian == '<':
            stf_file.write('\xff\xfe')
        stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'IHHI', 8, self.version, self.channel, self.frequency))

        stf_file.write('CHKL')
        stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'I', len(''.join(self.chunks))) + ''.join(self.chunks))

        for c in self.chunks:
            if self.__dict__[c.strip()] is None:
                continue

            matrix = self.__dict__[c.strip()]
            if len(matrix.shape) == 1:
                argument = 1
            else:
                argument = matrix.shape[1]
            data_size = matrix.shape[0] * argument * 8

            header = struct.pack(self.endian + 'dIIHdI', self.shift_length, matrix.shape[0], argument, self.bit_size, self.weight, data_size)
            stf_file.write(c + struct.pack(self.endian + 'I', len(header) + data_size) + header)

            for i in xrange(matrix.shape[0]):
                if argument == 1:
                    stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'd', matrix[i]))
                else:
                    for j in xrange(matrix.shape[1]):
                        stf_file.write(struct.pack(self.endian + 'd', matrix[i, j]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: %s <stf_file>' % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit()

    stf = STF()
    stf.loadfile(sys.argv[1])
    print(stf.F0)
```

Comment: いくつか質問記事を書かれていますが、該当記事を最初の方にたどっていくと、ここ [第1章　はじめに](https://sunpro.io/c89/pub/hiromu/ch01) に **「すべてPython 2.7.10で動作を確認」** との記述があり、使用しているモジュールやその版数も書かれています。これらのプログラムや版数の環境と同じものを用意してから動作確認していますか？

Comment: python2が使えなくなると聞いたのでpython3.7で行なっています

Comment: `python 2.x 3.x 違い`とかで検索した記事を良く読むと判りますが、2.x系用に書かれたプログラムは、そのまま3.x系では実行出来ない場合が多いです。初心者だと、何が原因か・その対応をどうすればいいか等を調べるのも大変な場合が多いでしょう。別に2.x系が明日無くなるとか動作させるのが違法になるとかでは無いので、対象としているプログラムを理解したいだけなら、書かれている環境を用意して動作確認したほうが、問題になることが少ないでしょう。あるいはとくにそのプログラムにこだわらないなら、3.x系用に書かれたプログラムを探した方が良い場合もあります。

Comment: @user37221 前回の質問にもコメントしましたが、python2 と python3 では`struct.unpack()` の仕様に違いがあるため、このスクリプトは python3 では想定する動作にはなりません。

Comment: わかりました。2.x系の環境を作って確認してみます